# Scheduling strategy behind AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, fifo, aws-batch

I am wondering what the scheduling strategy behind AWS Batch looks like. The official documentation on this topic doesn't provide much details:

> The AWS Batch scheduler evaluates when, where, and how to run jobs that have been submitted to a job queue. Jobs run in approximately the order in which they are submitted as long as all dependencies on other jobs have been met.

(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_scheduling.html)

"Approximately" fifo is quite vaque. Especially as the execution order I observed when testing AWS Batch did't look like fifo. 
Did I miss something? Is there a possibility to change the scheduling strategy, or configure Batch to execute the jobs in the exact order in which they were submitted?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Batch for a while now, and it has always seemed to behave in roughly a FIFO manner. Jobs that are submitted first will generally be started first, but because of limitations with distributed systems, this general rule won't work out perfectly. Jobs with dependencies are kept in the PENDING state until their dependencies have completed, and then they go into the RUNNABLE state. In my experience, whenever Batch is ready to run more jobs from the RUNNABLE state, it picks the job with the earliest time submitted.

However, there are some caveats. First, if Job A was submitted first but requires 8 cores while Job B was submitted later but only requires 4 cores, Job B might be selected first if Batch has only 4 cores available. Second, after a job leaves the RUNNABLE state, it goes into STARTING while Batch downloads the Docker image and gets the container ready to run. Depending on a number of factors, jobs that were submitted at the same time may take longer or shorter in the STARTING state. Finally, if a job fails and is retried, it goes back into the PENDING state with its original time submitted. When Batch decides to select more jobs to run, it will generally select the job with the earliest submit date, which will be the job that failed. If other jobs have started before the first job failed, the first job will start its second run after the other jobs.

There's no way to configure Batch to be perfectly FIFO because it's a distributed system, but generally if you submit jobs with the same compute requirements spaced a few seconds apart, they'll execute in the same order you submitted them.